# Having trouble sorting leaves in ascending order for binary tree

Tags: java, recursion

So the original problem is Write the method chechkLeaves(), which should return true if the leaves of the tree are sorted in increasing order and false otherwise. You can assume that data for all internal nodes are null. You will find it useful to define additional recursive helper methods for this problem.

Edit: My code is working now, but how can I modify the code so that I the val is passed in as a parameter rather than global variable?

```
   static int val = 0;
      static public boolean checkLeaves(Node root) {
         // int val = 0;
          if(root.data != 0 ) {
              if(root.data > val) {
                  val = root.data;
                  return true;
              } else {
                  return false;
              }
          } else {
              return checkLeaves(root.left) && checkLeaves(root.right);

          }
      }
```

Comment: *"but it's not working."* Please be more specific - does it give the wrong result, does it give an error message, is it an infinite loop, or something else? You need to give full details, including what input you are testing on and what output you expect. See also how to write a [mcve].

Comment: please read my edit now.

Comment: Your global variable isn't being used. You can delete it and the code will behave the same. This is because your integer val in the parameters is shadowing that variable anyways.

Comment: It's actually doing the opposite, not giving me the correct solution when I keep the instance variable.

Comment: Have you taken this into account?  *"You can assume that data for all internal nodes are null."*.  It looks like your code is assuming that `node.data` is an `int`, not a reference type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a way for you to be able to do this traversal of the leaves with comparison *without* a global variable. This is something that can be accomplished with passing-by-reference, but Java doesn't have such a feature. So, you have two options:

**Option 1)** Stick with this static variable.

**Option 2)** Make `val` a parameter as an array, as such:

```
   private static public boolean checkLeaves(Node root, int[] val) {
    if (root.data != 0) {
     if (root.data > val[0]) {
      val[0] = root.data;
      return true;
     } else {
      return false;
     }
    } else {
     return checkLeaves(root.left, val) && checkLeaves(root.right, val);
    }
   }
```

And to call it:

```
checkLeaves(root, new int[] { Integer.MIN_VALUE });
```

By making it an array, you can emulate that "pass by reference" behavior. That is, updating the original value of the variable by having a reference to the original value. Everything in Java is pass-by-value, so the value of the variable is passed to the parameter, not the reference to it.

## Note

I suggest you name your variables a little more descriptive. For example, instead of `val`, you could name it `previousLeafValue` or something.

Also, a good practice to follow is making everything as "private" as possible. In option 2 you can see my code have the method with a private access modifier. The same is true for your static variable. Make it a habit to make things private by habit, then expand their modifiers as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help! one last thing, I need help writing findMin() for lazy deletion in binary search trees, but can't come up with a soluition.

Comment: @user11452926 - 1) That is a different problem to the question you asked.  2)  "I need help" is not a question.